# Prevent delay in content generated by Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript countdown function to count down to a date.  Problem is that when the page loads, there is a slight delay in the countdown number appearing.  This would be acceptable if it was only one page on the site, but the function is going to go into a site-wide banner and so the delay is apparent on every single page visited throughout the site. It's pretty janky.

Is there a way to prevent this delay in loading the javascript generated content?

I know I can also add the text next to the numbers in the function, so it all loads at once instead of having the number pop in between the text, but I would like to avoid the delay entirely if possible.

Here is the code:

```
        var target_date = new Date("Dec 18, 2014").getTime();
         var days;
         var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
         setInterval(function () {
             var current_date = new Date().getTime();
            var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
             days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
             countdown.innerHTML = days + " " ;  

        }, 1000);
```

and here is a fiddle so you can see what I'm talking about.

http://jsfiddle.net/cxythc7p/5/

Comment: Why dont you try and send the Current date from the server side instead

Comment: I only have access to the front-end on this site :/  Have to use a CMS and load scripts in the same 'hot spots' I put regular HTML...

Comment: Here I have a question then. What if my date is somehow set to 22-Nov-2011?? I'll that countdown to be some 'only 1122 days left!'? Is that OKAY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you wait 1 second before you write the content. You need to execute it right away. Take the code out of the interval, put it into a function. Execute the function and have the interval call that function.

```js
var target_date = new Date("Dec 18, 2014").getTime();
var days;
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

function myCounter() {
  var current_date = new Date().getTime();
  var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
  days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
  countdown.innerHTML = days + " ";
}
setInterval(myCounter, 1000);
myCounter();
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Also seems weird you run it every second when it is calculated in days. Performance there could be improved.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a reason...I copied this code from somewhere. I will also figure out how to improve the performance as you mentioned. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

As epascarello said, you wait 1 second, here is the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/cxythc7p/6/.

But there are also other things you should consider:

- You could start with the value inside `#countdown`  already initialized (by server code).
- You should run your JavaScript as early as possible if you want that Javascript to be executed as early as possible